# SolidJS - Unhandled error when testing `data.error` in `createResource` with `vitest`

Tags: javascript, solid-js, vitest

I'm trying to test a SolidJS component which shows a "Track not found" message when returning 404 from the API. The code works fine when running, but Vitest throws a `Vitest caught 1 unhandled error during the test run. This might cause false positive tests.` error.

Similar.tsx:

```
const Tracks: Component<Params> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Show
      when={!tracks.error}
      fallback={<ErrorMessage message="Track not found" />}
    >
      <div class="tracks">
        <For
          each={tracks()}
          fallback={<ErrorMessage message="No similar tracks found" />}
        >
          {(track) => (
            <Track
              name={track.name}
              artist={track.artist.name}
              image={track.image[3]['#text']}
              url={track.url}
            />
          )}
        </For>
      </div>
    </Show>
  );
};
```

And this is the test suite I'm running:

```js
it('renders a "Track not found" message if API returns 404', async () => {
      vitest
        .spyOn(fetchSimilarTracks, 'default')
        .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Track not found'));
      const { findByText } = renderSimilar({
        track: 'hdsauidhas',
        artist: 'hdsduhsd',
      });

      expect(await findByText('Track not found')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the docs a bit, I realized that I missed the following entry:

> data works like a normal signal getter: use data() to read the last returned value of fetchData. But it also has extra reactive properties: data.loading tells you if the fetcher has been called but not returned, and data.error tells you if the request has errored out; if so, it contains the error thrown by the fetcher. (Note: if you anticipate errors, you may want to wrap createResource in an **ErrorBoundary**.)

So what I did was, instead of using `<Show />` for conditionally rendering the Error Message, wrap `Tracks` into an `<ErrorBoundary />` and provide `<ErrorMessage />` as a fallback there:

```
<ErrorBoundary fallback={<ErrorMessage message="Track not found" />}>
  <Tracks track={params.track} artist={params.artist} />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

So this is how `<Tracks />` should look like:

```
const Tracks: Component<Params> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div class="tracks">
      <For
        each={tracks()}
        fallback={<ErrorMessage message="No similar tracks found" />}
      >
        {(track) => (
          <Track
            name={track.name}
            artist={track.artist.name}
            image={track.image[3]['#text']}
            url={track.url}
          />
        )}
      </For>
    </div>
  );
};
```